# ¿ Cómo enlazar reduce en hadoop con steps?

Tags: python, map, reduce, hadoop, reducer

Gracias por las aportaciones. Creo no me aclaro. Realice un programa en hadoop con map reduce que me busca cuantos clientes "buenos" tiene cada pais. Son en realidad dos ficheros a los que hago también una operación join.

Al final, la salida de mi primer ejemplo es :

```
["South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"]    1
["South Sudan"] 1
["Spain"]   3
...
```

Eso lo hago con varios map reduce y steps, ( ver código en amarillo)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después le añado el reducer3 y me continua dando exactamente la misma salida, no lo entiendo. Se que lo ejecuta porque si en ese reducer3 hago max(value)+1000, modifíca la salida.
¿ qué entiendo mal?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Mejor ver la respuesta aquí. Esta mejor explicado de como yo lo haría. Gracias.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74415367/how-to-steps-differences-reduce-in-hadoop